# How to determine if a relative path is outside of a virtual path

Tags: asp.net

I'm using the following function to convert paths into a valid Virtual Path:

```
public string GetFullPath(string path)
{
    Ensure.Argument.NotNullOrEmpty(path, "path");

    if (path[0] == '~') // a virtual path e.g. ~/assets/style.less
    {
        return path;
    }

    if (VirtualPathUtility.IsAbsolute(path)) // an absolute path e.g. /assets/style.less
    {
        return VirtualPathUtility.ToAppRelative(path,
            HostingEnvironment.IsHosted ? HostingEnvironment.ApplicationVirtualPath : "/");
    }

    // otherwise, assume relative e.g. style.less or ../../variables.less
    return VirtualPathUtility.Combine(VirtualPathUtility.AppendTrailingSlash(currentFileDirectory), path);
}
```

This passes all my tests other than for when the input `path` is a relative path, **above** the website directory.

For example given a `currentFileDirectory` of `~/foo/bar` and a relative path of `../../../` I want to detect this and attempt to fix the path.

Comment: Why not use Server.MapPath which will map virtual to physical directories?

Comment: I'm working with different virtual path providers so can't touch the physical file system.

Comment: It also supports dos relative paths but nothing beyond the root of the web server (for security rasons, asp.net security cannot be applied outside the web site. Note that random storage can be accessed by creating a virtual directory that points at it. if mappath returns nothing an invalid path (or one that points outside the structure exists. This should be enough to validate the desired path.

Comment: Valid point, you want to provide an answer? If not I'll answer myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Server.MapPath is an easy way to validate either virtual or dos style paths. Validation is restricted for security reasons from validating any physical paths that are outside the web site. See my comment above.

Comment: How does Server.MapPath prevents from accessing a file within a virtual directory (Pointed to a folder outside the web application directory) VS a folder within the web application directory? In either case the application is accessing a location (virtual directory) within the application folder. But in reality the paths are different.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on Mike's answer we can validate whether a relative path attempts to go outside of the physical web site directory by:

1. Getting the combined path of the current path and relative path using `Path.GetFullPath`
2. Getting the file system path of the attempted path using `Server.MapPath`
3. Getting the file system path of the root of the application
4. Validating that the attempted path exists within the root path

Example:

```
var currentFileDirectory = "~/foo/bar";
var relativePath = "../../../";
var attemptedPath = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(currentFileDirectory), relativePath)); // 1 + 2
var rootPath = Server.MapPath("~/"); // 3

if (attemptedPath.IndexOf(rootPath, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) == -1) // 4
{
    throw new Exception(string.Format("Path {0} is outside path {1}", 
        rootPath, HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath));
}
```

Comment: If a virtual directory is pointed to a path outside the web application folder then this code will fail.